# How to display the xml page in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: xml, google-chrome, firefox, xslt

How to display the XML page(with xslt) in Firefox & Chrome.
when i try with IE ,its working, but not working in Firefox & Chrome.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sample.xsl"?>
<root>
  <title> This contains an 'embedded' HTML document </title>
  <document>
    <![CDATA[
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
      <body>
        <h4>Team Names test</h4>
        <ul class="listStyle">
          <li>REAP</li>
          <li>NAMS</li>
          <li>NCAT</li>
          <li>YARDI</li>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
    ]]>
  </document> 
</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body class="chunk">
        <document type="long" format="html" >         
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="document"/>
        </document>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

While opening the XML page(with xslt) in Firefox,only it showing text.
when i try with IE ,its working, but not working in Firefox & Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`disable-output-escaping` is an optional serialization feature, as Firefox does not serialize the result tree of the XSLT transformation but simply renders it `disable-output-escaping` is not supported in Firefox, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#Can_I_do_disable-output-escaping.3F.

For Chrome I am not sure, you haven't really described from where you are loading the file, check the error console of Chrome whether it displays anything giving you a clue as to why something does not work as you expect it.

As a workaround for Mozilla/Firefox, as you have a complete document you want to render, you could choose an iframe and use a `data` URL. That works for me with http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013072901.xml respectively the stylesheet http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2013072901.xsl with a current version of Firefox, Chrome and Opera. It does not work with IE 10 however. Perhaps it needs the HTML in the `src` attribute properly base64 encoded.